# Change color of pin on map after pressing button on another screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, annotations, mkmapview

[image] [image] [image]

I need to find a way to change the pin color when the map is loaded by pushing a button from another screen.

For example, the original pins are all red, but when I go to a page and push the map button, it has to lead me to the map view and the coordinates of that location have to be marked with a green pin.

I already have the map set up and the setup of making the pins all red.

Any help is appreciated.

So, just a recap:
Page with map with red pin --> click pin, click annotation (another view opens) --> inside view, there is a button (eg. @"change pin color"), click button -->  page with map with green pin opens. (Look at the example above with pictures.)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is change something in the data that represents that pin. The annotation. When you switch back to the map the annotation will be redrawn and your `viewForAnnotation` method will be called at which point you check the attributes and draw the right colour.

Comment: But how do I get this to change between separate views, since I have a lot of these types of views which need to bring up a different color and then go back to the original color when the back button is pressed?

Comment: You need to push a view controller onto the navigation controller stack. If you don't know what that means you'll need to do a bit of research. Once that is sorted give that new view controller an attribute that the parent view controller can read after the child view controller is dismissed. Then read that attribute and change your annotation if required.

Comment: Is there an action that is something like:
if (previous screen name: @"")
{
}
Because this would make it easiest for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just declare a new constructor to set the colour of your choice?

```
// ViewControllerB .h file
@interface ViewControllerB
{
    UIColor *pinColor;
}

-(id)initWithPinColor:(UIColor *)chosenPinColor;

...

// ViewControllerB .m file
-(id)initWithPinColor:(UIColor *)chosenPinColor
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        pinColor = chosenPinColor;
    }

    return self;
}

...

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *annotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationViewID];

    if(!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    // this will use the pinColor stored in the constructor
    annotationView.pinColor = pinColor;        
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Then you can simply do this in ViewControllerA:

```
// ViewControllerA .m file
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

...

-(void)showMapWithPinColor:(id)sender
{
    ViewControllerB *vc = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithPinColor:[UIColor green]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a navigation controller, so is there a way around it?

Comment: If you're using a custom UIView class, you can create a protocol inside it, declare a property of type id<CustomUIViewDelegate> delegate and also in your protocol, create a non-optional method (e.g. -(void)changePinColor;) that your original view controller must implement. Inside your "change color" button tapped callback method, you can call [self.delegate changePinColor]; Then in your original view controller, I assume you stored the last tapped pin annotation view, so just go something like lastSelectedPin.pinColor = [UIColor purpleColor]; in the implemented protocol method.

Comment: Another approach is to declare a property MKAnnotationView in your custom UIView class and assign to it, the original lastSelectedPin from your original view controller. Then when you execute buttonTapped method in your custom class, you simply go originalPin.pinColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

Comment: I'm still pretty confused... Is there a function that can change the settings in the map while it is being opened from a specific xib?