# Is there a way to change what the disclosure button in Apple Maps does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, apple-maps

I have tried to use MapView, but after finding out that I won't be able to add directions, I am switching to Apple Maps. At first I wanted to add a navigation bar so that I could go back to my app from Apple Maps, but I have been informed that that's not possible. So now, I want to know if I can change the page that opens when I click an annotation view disclosure button in Apple Maps, and possibly lead it back to my app that way by opening one of my local view controllers.

Apple is giving me a hard time with navigating these maps...

If it is possible, please give a code sample or something, or explain what else I can do to lead Apple Maps back to my app.

So far, I use this code to open Apple Maps:

```
- (IBAction)mapPressed1:(id)sender
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D miamizoo = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.613336,-80.398437);
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:miamizoo addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *item = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
item.name = @"Miami Zoo";
[item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
}
```

Thanks; all help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do, draw a path from your current location to the destination on a MKMapView or do you mean Siri voice turn-by-turn navigation directions ? I previously used Google Directions API to get the polyline path, decode it and draw it on MKMapView as a MKOverlay.

Comment: I need to draw a path and the driving directions, and I have over 100 locations on my map.

Comment: "Driving directions" is that text based driving directions or turn by turn VOICE driving directions ? If it's text based driving directions and drawing path on map, Google Direction's API lets you do that, although they have specifically stated you cannot use it on non-Google Maps, if you set your target iOS to 5.0 you're not breaking their agreement :D Otherwise, there's also Google's Map API for iOS which I haven't tried yet, might be the better option. The app I wrote before had around 247 locations all plotted on the map.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still have another problem concerning maps... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677966/change-color-of-pin-on-map-after-pressing-button-on-another-screen

Answer (score 2):

my initial quess is that it will not be possible because apple maps is an independent app from the one you're writing. 
Apple maps is a ready, closed up application without any modification possibilities, so you will not be able to change the behavior of the disclosure button / add a bar into apple maps.
Anyone, please prove me wrong, because I also was puzzled about the missing direction feature in the map API.You will either have to use overlays for directions in map API or you bite the bullet and buy a ready made direction api for maps.
The way I'm currently doing it is similar to yours. I start up apple maps with a direction request and change into it, no overlays.

I hope they will make up for that in ios7.
They do make up for it. Didnt have the chance to put my hands on the ios7 beta, but it will be there.
El